# jQuery click event firing immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, closures

I have the following code in the web app I'm developing:

```
var bgcolor = '';
var row = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++)
{
    // Set alternating background colors
    bgcolor = ( i%2 == 0) ? ' style=\'background-color: white;\'': ' style=\'background-color: whitesmoke;\'';
    $( "div.row" ).append("\
        <div class='search_container'"+bgcolor+">\
            <div class='search_result_client_heading'>"+result.data[i]['client_name']+"</div>\
            <div class='search_result_industry_heading'>"+result.data[i]['industry_name']+"</div>\
            <div class='search_result_yield_heading'>Saved: "+result.data[i]['actual_impact']+" "+result.data[i]['impact_type_name']+" / "+formatCurrency(String(result.data[i]['actual_savings']))+"</div>\
            <div class='search_result_problem_heading'>"+nl2br( result.data[i]['problem'] )+"</div>\
            <div class='detail_button_holder'>\
                <a class='btn search_result_button' id='view_results_"+result.data[i]['record_id']+"' href='#'>View details &raquo;</a>\
            </div>\
        </div>");

    $( "#view_results_"+result.data[i]['record_id'] ).click( show_result_dialog(i, result) );
}
```

and then a separate named function that simply populates the created div with different values, depending on which button is clicked:

```
function show_result_dialog(row, result)
{
    $( "#search-result-dialog-client" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Client</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['client_name']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-industry" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Industry</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['industry_name']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-contact" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Contact</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['contact_name']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-journey" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Journey</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['journey_name']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-focus_area" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Focus Area</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['focus_area']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-problem" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Problem</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['problem']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-approach" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Approach</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['approach']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-tactics" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Tactics</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['tactics']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-delivery_date" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Delivery Date</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['delivery_date']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-impact_type" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Impact Type</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['impact_type_name']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-estimated_impact" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Estimated Impact</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['estimated_impact']+" "+result.data[row]['impact_type_name']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-actual_impact" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Actual Impact</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['actual_impact']+" "+result.data[row]['impact_type_name']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-estimated_savings" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Estimated Savings</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+formatCurrency(String(result.data[row]['estimated_savings']))+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-actual_savings" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Actual Savings</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+formatCurrency(String(result.data[row]['actual_savings']))+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-nps" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>NPS</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['nps']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog-keywords" ).empty().append("<div class='search_result_label'>Keywords</div><div class='search_result_value'>"+result.data[row]['keywords']+"</div>");
    $( "#search-result-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;
}
```

in the code `result` is an array of data returned by an AJAX call (this code is all in the success function)

My problem is that the click handler is firing immediately upon page load. I was hoping someone could explain to me why that is, and if there is a way around that, since I need to pass that function the `i` value from the loop, so if I house an anonymous function in the click event, then I have problems with closure, and always end up with the last i value, so every button opens the same data. I have tried various techniques around that without success, including returning an anonymous function inside of the main anonymous function and vice versa. I've spent the last two days on Google trying to find the solution, and so far nothing has worked.

Comment: because you are calling a function, not assigning a reference!

Comment: FWIW, you should alias `result.data[row]` to another variable to avoid repetition (and for performance), and `.empty().append(...)` can be replaced with `.html(...)`.

Comment: better yet, make the HTML static and use element IDs and DOM traversal to just replace the specific bits of text that need updating instead of deleting and recreating the same DOM elements over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two problems that I can see.

The first, as identified by other posters, is not writing `function() { ... }` around the call to `show_result_dialog()`.

The second, is using `.click` instead of `.on`.  The former method is (confusingly) used to both *register* and to *trigger* click handlers, whereas the latter can only *register*.  If you had used `.on` the problem would likely have been much easier to see.

The third is that you're trying to use a loop variable inside a closure, which never works.  `i` will have the last value it had at the end of the loop, not the value it had when the call to `.click` was made.

The simplest fix for the latter problem is to use the `data` parameter to `.on()` to pass the required parameters:

```
$("#view_results_" + result.data[i]['record_id'] ).on('click', {
   row: i, result: result
}, show_result_dialog);

function show_result_dialog(ev) {
    var row = ev.data.row;
    var result = ev.data.result;
    ...
}
```

Other (more efficient) methods exist to solve the loop problem, but this will work and is pretty trivial to understand.

Comment: two downvotes for not initially spotting the `i` loop problem when the topic of the question was an immediately firing handler?  That's pretty harsh.

Comment: I think whether i is in the closure or not is outside the scope of the question. The question was why does the function fire. Are we supposed to lint all the code for errors regardless of the question being asked?

Comment: I don't care how many downvotes you got, your answer worked perfectly. (though I had figured out the i loop problem, I just hadn't been able to work out a fix.) Thanks very much! I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Some people apparently have no clue about JavaScript. They should not be allowed to vote. Or someone (two of them) was (were) just mad at you.

Comment: @FelixKling and mad at some of the other answers too!  I don't mind people getting mad at me if I'm being a dick, I know I can be a bit abrasive on here sometimes, but those downvotes were just excessive.  As it stands I'm still on +2/-2.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function yourself here `.click( show_result_dialog(i, result) );`
There is a difference between invoking a function `show_result_dialog()` and passing its reference `show_result_dialog`.

You need to either pass your arguments as event data:

```
.click( {index: i, result: result}, show_result_dialog );
```

or simply wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
.click( function() { return show_result_dialog(i, result) });
```

Comment: well your second one would be incorrect because i would be equal to the length of the array when the click happens.

Comment: No, it is not incorrect - it answers the question correctly: it stops the function from being executed there and passes in arguments. The fact that there is a different error somewhere in his code should not affect the validity of my answer.

Comment: It does not answer it correctly and the error is in YOUR code. `i` will be the length of the array when the user clicks the item in the second example you posted.

Comment: The error is NOT in my code. My solution works perfectly if you create a scope for i: http://jsfiddle.net/ffYdP/2/
As I said, the value of i is of no connection to the question being asked (why does that function executing). Please get your facts straight before down voting and watering downs.

Comment: The OP commented on the same exact answer in one of the deleted posts that it was 5, they do not understand scoping, so your answer would have had to show the wrapped function.

Comment: OK, I wont argue anymore - no point. The way I see it the question was not _how to preserve the value of i_. The question was _jQuery click event firing immediately_. My answer is correct irrespective of the number and value of the arguments passed in. I hate being down-voted for being concise.

Comment: @Andrei Nemes Still, there is a mistake in your anonymous function. It cannot work as is (hence your jsfiddle shows that does not work). I would propose a variation of epascarello's solution. Wrapping up the anonymous function on the strictly needed level : http://jsfiddle.net/ffYdP/3/